# Swift 5 & CloudKit: recordFetchedBlock does not work on real device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloudkit, watchos

I'm thankfully using https://medium.com/better-programming/data-persistence-cloudkit-b12e575bd85c to create my first app using CloudKit and it works all perfectly, as long as I don't run the watchKit App on my real Apple Watch with watchOS 7.

When it's about retrieving the records stored in iCloud, the *recordFetchedBlock* simply does not execute.

```
    func getCounterFromCloud() {
        print("Starting getCounterFromCloud...")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Count", predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate", ascending: false)]
        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        counterCloudCollector.removeAll()
        counterRecordIDs.removeAll()

        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
            self.counterCloudCollector.append(record["count"]!)
            self.counterRecordIDs.append(record.recordID)
            print("Operation FetchedBlock is done.")
        }

        operation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.counterCloud = self.counterCloudCollector[0]
                print("Should have received from cloud.")
                }
            }
        database.add(operation)
    }
```

I have the exact same code running in the iPhone version which is not a problem. As I use one Apple ID for development and one on my private phone, I've set my CloudKit Container to *Production* in the Dashboard but because I thought it could be an issue with my Apple ID but it doesn't help. (And the iPhone version works fine on my private Apple ID.)

Any idea anyone?

Comment: Change the operation to a CKFetchRecordsOperation and the queryCompletionBlock to a fetchRecordsCompletionBlock.

Comment: @johnelemans Thanks for your advice. I've been trying this for hours and hours with different tutorials but I don't have any success with that. 
Could you please specify? It is the one last puzzle piece I need to finish my app.